# Soap and Body tags encapsulated twice in the response in axis2

Tags: apache-axis

I am trying to run a apache axis2 webservice client and Im getting thrown an exeption like given below

***org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body 
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)***

Here is the wsdl for the webservice

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
- 
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://wtp" 
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" 
xmlns:ns="http://wtp" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"> 
<wsdl:documentation> Please Type your service description here 
</wsdl:documentation> 
- 
<wsdl:types> 
- 
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://wtp" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
attributeFormDefault="qualified"> 
- 
<xs:element name="authenticate"> 
- 
<xs:complexType> 
- 
<xs:sequence> 
<xs:element name="loginname" type="xs:string" nillable="true" 
minOccurs="0" /> 
<xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" nillable="true" 
minOccurs="0" /> 
</xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType> 
</xs:element> 
- 
<xs:element name="authenticateResponse"> 
- 
<xs:complexType> 
- 
<xs:sequence> 
<xs:element name="return" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /> 
</xs:sequence> 
</xs:complexType> 
</xs:element> 
</xs:schema> 
</wsdl:types> 
- 
<wsdl:message name="authenticateRequest"> 
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:authenticate" /> 
</wsdl:message> 
- 
<wsdl:message name="authenticateResponse"> 
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:authenticateResponse" /> 
</wsdl:message> 
- 
<wsdl:portType name="LoginPortType"> 
- 
<wsdlperation name="authenticate"> 
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="urn:authenticate" message="ns:authenticateRequest" /> 
<wsdlutput wsaw:Action="urn:authenticateResponse" 
message="ns:authenticateResponse" /> 
</wsdlperation> 
</wsdl:portType> 
- 
<wsdl:binding name="LoginSoap11Binding" type="ns:LoginPortType"> 
<soap:binding style="document" 
transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
- 
<wsdlperation name="authenticate"> 
<soapperation style="document" soapAction="urn:authenticate" /> 
- 
<wsdl:input> 
<soap:body use="literal" /> 
</wsdl:input> 
- 
<wsdlutput> 
<soap:body use="literal" /> 
</wsdlutput> 
</wsdlperation> 
</wsdl:binding> 
- 
<wsdl:binding name="LoginSoap12Binding" type="ns:LoginPortType"> 
<soap12:binding style="document" 
transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
- 
<wsdlperation name="authenticate"> 
<soap12peration style="document" soapAction="urn:authenticate" /> 
- 
<wsdl:input> 
<soap12:body use="literal" /> 
</wsdl:input> 
- 
<wsdlutput> 
<soap12:body use="literal" /> 
</wsdlutput> 
</wsdlperation> 
</wsdl:binding> 
- 
<wsdl:binding name="LoginHttpBinding" type="ns:LoginPortType"> 
<http:binding verb="POST" /> 
- 
<wsdlperation name="authenticate"> 
<httpperation location="authenticate" /> 
- 
<wsdl:input> 
<mime:content type="text/xml" part="parameters" /> 
</wsdl:input> 
- 
<wsdlutput> 
<mime:content type="text/xml" part="parameters" /> 
</wsdlutput> 
</wsdlperation> 
</wsdl:binding> 
- 
<wsdl:service name="Login"> 
- 
<wsdl:port name="LoginHttpSoap11Endpoint" binding="ns:LoginSoap11Binding"> 
<soap:address 
location="http://localhost:8080/Navigato/services/Login.LoginHttpSoap11Endpoint/" /> 
</wsdl:port> 
- 
<wsdl:port name="LoginHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:LoginSoap12Binding"> 
<soap12:address 
location="http://localhost:8080/Navigato/services/Login.LoginHttpSoap12Endpoint/" /> 
</wsdl:port> 
- 
<wsdl:port name="LoginHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:LoginHttpBinding"> 
<http:address 
location="http://localhost:8080/Navigato/services/Login.LoginHttpEndpoint/" /> 
</wsdl:port> 
</wsdl:service> 
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Following are the soap request and response packets from soap ui

### SOAP REQUEST

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<soapenv:Body> 
<ns1:authenticate xmlns:ns1="http://wtp"> 
<ns1:loginname>john</ns1:loginname> 
<ns1:password>123</ns1:password> 
</ns1:authenticate> 
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

### SOAP RESPONSE

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<soapenv:Body> 
<ns:authenticateResponse xmlns:ns="http://wtp"> 
<ns:return>1</ns:return> 
</ns:authenticateResponse> 
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But by the time the response is reaching the client stub, stub receives it 
as follows

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<soapenv:Body> 
<soapenv:Envelope> 
<soapenv:Body> 
<ns:authenticateResponse xmlns:ns="http://wtp"> 
<ns:return>1</ns:return> 
</ns:authenticateResponse> 
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope> 
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here the Soap and Body are encapsulated twice

As a result of this, client stub is unable to parse and throwing the 
following error.

***org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body 
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)***

### Client Code

```
public class LoginClient 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
            LoginStub stub = new LoginStub();
            Authenticate auth = new Authenticate();
            auth.setLoginname("john");
            auth.setPassword("123");
            AuthenticateResponse res = stub.authenticate(auth);
            System.out.println(res.get_return());
        } catch (AxisFault e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your client code is written?..Have you set the content-type of the messagecorrectly..
At some point, axis2 thinks the message is not a soap message and wraps again with a soap envelope..
When you receive the response in axis2 check the content-type of it..it should be text/xml

Comment: The response of the content type is given as text/xml itself.I have provided the client which is a test scenario added to the question above.Thanks in advance.